P is a point and PM, PN are perpendiculars from P to the ZX and XY planes respectively. If OP makes angles $\theta, \alpha, \beta, \gamma$, with OMN

P is a point and PM, PN are perpendiculars from P to the ZX and XY planes respectively. If OP makes angles $\theta, \alpha, \beta, \gamma$, with the plane OMN and the $XY, YZ, ZX$ planes respectively, then find the value of $\sin^2\theta(\csc^2\alpha+\csc^2\beta+\csc^2\gamma)$

My Attempt:
If $P$ is $(a,b,c)$ then $M$ is $(a,0,c)$ and $N$ is $(a,b,0)$
Also, $\cos^2\alpha+\cos^2\beta+\cos^2\gamma=1$
That gives, $\sin^2\alpha+\sin^2\beta+\sin^2\gamma=2$
Not sure how to convert it to cosec.

The answer is straightforward and corresponds to my understanding of the problem.
Since the plane $OMN$ is provided, $M\ne O\ne N$. Let $r=|OP|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}$. Then $r>0$ and we have $$\sin\alpha=\frac cr=\frac {|PN|}{|OP|},\sin\beta=\frac ar,\mbox{ and }\sin\gamma=\frac br=\frac {|PM|}{|OP|}.$$
Moreover, $a$, $b$, and $c$ are nonzero, since there are provided $$\csc\alpha=\frac 1{\sin\alpha}=\frac rc, \csc\beta=\frac 1{\sin\beta}=\frac ra,\mbox{ and }\csc\gamma=\frac 1{\sin\gamma}=\frac cr.$$
A normal vector $\bf{n}$ to the plane $OMN$ is orthogonal both to $OM$ and $ON$, so we can pick $${\bf n}=\vec{OM}\times \vec{ON}=\left|
\begin{matrix}
{\bf i} & {\bf j} & {\bf k}\\
a & 0 & c\\
a & b & 0
\end{matrix}
\right|=
(-bc,ac,ab).$$
Then $$\sin^2\theta=\left(\frac{\vec{OP}\cdot {\bf n}} {|OP|\cdot |{\bf n}|}\right)^2=
\frac{(-abc+abc+abc)^2}{(a^2+b^2+c^2)(b^2c^2+a^2c^2+a^2b^2)}.$$
Therefore
$$\sin^2\theta\cdot (\csc^2\alpha+\csc^2\beta+\csc^2\gamma)=$$
$$\sin^2\theta\cdot \left(\frac 1{\sin^2\alpha}+\frac 1{\sin^2\beta}+\frac 1{\sin^2\gamma}\right)=$$
$$\frac{a^2b^2c^2}{(a^2+b^2+c^2)(b^2c^2+a^2c^2+a^2b^2)}\cdot \left(\frac {r^2}{c^2}+\frac {r^2}{a^2}+\frac {r^2}{b^2}\right)=$$
$$\frac{a^2b^2c^2}{(a^2+b^2+c^2)(b^2c^2+a^2c^2+a^2b^2)}\cdot (a^2+b^2+c^2)\cdot \frac {a^2b^2+b^2c^2+a^2c^2}{a^2b^2c^2}=1.$$
The simplicity of the answer cries that the problem has a simple geometric solution. But this was unknown a priori, so during contest short time it can be more strategically to follow this analytical solution
rather than to look for a geometric insight. I am weak in geometry, but have rather strong analytic skills. So a long ago, when I participated in many contests, I usually had quickly solved all nongeometrical problems and then devoted the remaining contest time to analytically solve the remaining geometric problem.

Lovely perspective in the last para, thanks.


P is a point and PM, PN are perpendiculars from P to the ZX and XY planes respectively. If OP makes angles $\theta, \alpha, \beta, \gamma$, with the plane OMN and the $XY, YZ, ZX$ planes respectively, then find the value of $\sin^2\theta(\csc^2\alpha+\csc^2\beta+\csc^2\gamma)$

Let $P$ be $(a,b,c)$, then $M$ is $(a,0,c)$ and $N$ is $(a,b,0)$
The normal of the plane $OMN$ would be the cross product of $\vec{OM}$ and $\vec{ON}$
Therefore, $\vec{n}=\vec{OM}\times\vec{ON}$
This question is essentially about finding the angle between a line (OP) and plane (OMN),
$$\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta\right)=\frac{\vec{n}\cdot\vec{OP}}{|\vec{n}||\vec{OP}|}$$
$$\vec{OP}=a\hat{i}+b\hat{j}+c\hat{k},\,|\vec{OP}|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}$$
$$\vec{n}=-bc\hat{i}+ac\hat{j}+ab\hat{k},\,|\vec{n}|=\sqrt{(ab)^2+(bc)^2+(ac)^2}$$
$$\sin\left(\theta\right)=\frac{abc}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}\sqrt{(ab)^2+(bc)^2+(ac)^2}}\tag1$$
From the definition of direction cosines;
$$\sin(\alpha)=\frac{\vec{OP}\cdot\hat{k}}{|\vec{OP}|} ||\,\sin(\beta)=\frac{\vec{OP}\cdot\hat{i}}{|\vec{OP}|}|| \,\sin(\gamma)=\frac{\vec{OP}\cdot\hat{j}}{|\vec{OP}|}$$
The order you define your
$$\sin(\alpha)=\frac{c}{\sqrt{(ab)^2+(bc)^2+(ac)^2}} || \sin(\beta)=\frac{a}{\sqrt{(ab)^2+(bc)^2+(ac)^2}} || \sin(\gamma)=\frac{b}{\sqrt{(ab)^2+(bc)^2+(ac)^2}}\tag2$$
I think you can solve it from here (use $1,2$)...
